# Linux based Operating System (distribution) for python, Maxima, C programming and jupyter notebook

Tags: linux, software-installation, distribution-choice, software-distribution

We are fairly new to Linux. We are looking for Suitable Linux based Operating System (distribution) for python, Maxima (computer algebra system), c programming and jupyter notebook. We want to install these on 30 computer systems. Which Linux based Operating System would be useful? Is there any distribution which comes pre-installed with one or more of these? We will prefer to have some good GUI as users are not acquainted with Linux but familiar with Windows operating system. Ours is educational institute. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: they are all suitable, but you should probably look into a long term distro, so you don't have to do major OS upgrades every six months.   ubuntu LTS, rhel  (or almalinux ) would be good.  anything else will require more upkeep.   Once you dip your toes and figure out what you need, you can always switch.  Dont forget backups and configuration management!

Comment: You should install a specific distro on all computers and check the necessary commands  for installing the software you want. Once you have those commands you should make a shell script (e.g. bash) that will execute the commands used for installing your software.

Comment: For **c programming** you can use `gcc` or `clang`.  **Python** is usually installed on all Linux distros (unless you want to install a specific version that is not installed). About **Maxima** and **Jupyter Notebook** you should check what are the commands used for installing.

Comment: Maybe ask in https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Just about Linux distributions (other than the ones whose entire purpose is minimalism) typically come with Python (amongst other things) pre-installed.  Your question is one of those where if you ask ten people, you're likely to get fifteen answers because the answer is primarily based in personal preference or opinion.  Any mainstream Linux distribution is quite likely to meet your needs.